# Did ARCore supported on Android One?

Tags: operating-system, arcore

Did Android One support ARCore? I checked the ARCore offical website and Android One didn't mention there.

[https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices#android_play]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment the list you reference is all the supported devices - this is because Google reportedly has to check the performance and do some calibration work per device.

I think, given the performance requirements, it will be mostly mid to high end devices initially which will likely exclude Android One type phones.

In discussions on the ARCore repository issues list they have explained in the past that adding devices requires (https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/217):

- The devices to have a fast enough CPU to run the map-building algorithms.
- Testing to ensure the camera and IMU provide consistent timestamps across exposure, cpu load, etc. This can require OS updates in some cases.
- Calibration of the camera and IMU, per device model. For now this can only happen in custom-designed robotic calibration stations using special software.